# NoActivityFound for Browsable Activity

Tags: android, webbrowser-control

Please help me out. I want to open a html5 file through an browser. But i Have no idea why am i getting this NoActivityFound for Browsable Activity Error.

Here is my Code

```
String directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/cam/";
            String html = "/res/raw/test.html";

            html = html + directory;
            Uri fromFile = Uri.fromFile(new File(html));

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            browserIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                    "com.android.browser",
                    "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
            browserIntent.setData(fromFile);
            startActivity(browserIntent);
```

And in ANdroidManiFest i have written

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.example.openhtml.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Thanks a Lot.

Comment: emulator or real device?

Comment: Please paste your actual logcat error trace.

Comment: make sure that the browser is installed. some times it may not be there.

Comment: I am using real device

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
Here is my LOgCat Error.. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android load local html file and display in web browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937491/android-load-local-html-file-and-display-in-web-browser)